# Message pre-processing (topic - topic) - Kafka Connect API vs. Streams vs Kafka Consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

We're in need to do some pre-processing on every message (decrypt/re-encrypt with different keys) from one topic into another one.

I've been looking into using Kafka Connect since it provides a lot of good things out of the box (config management, offset storage, error handling, etc.).

But it also feels that I'd end implementing `SourceConnector` and `SinkConnector` to just move data between two topics and neither of those interfaces are meant to do `Topic A -> (Connector) -> Topic B`. Is this the right approach? Should I just use `SinkConnector` alone and have my `SourceTask.put()` do all the logic to write to Kafka?

Other options are `KafkaConsumer/Producer` and or Streams but these will then need its own instance(s) to run the logic, not offset retry error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> provides a lot of good things out of the box (config management, offset storage, error handling, etc.)

Config management shouldn't be harder than re-deploying an application, but that depends on any version control or CI/CD pipelines you may or may not have.

Kafka Producer/Consumer and Streams offer offset management, you just have to configure it to do anything but the defaults.

Error handling is fairly well-documented, don't just fire-and-forget if you care about detecting errors. Connect itself will stop consuming and producing under critical error conditions, not retry or skip messages.

> Neither of those interfaces are meant to do `Topic A -> (Connector) -> Topic B`"

Have you seen Confluent Replicator (licensed product)? That **is** Kafka Connect between two topics.

Else, have you seen MirrorMaker? That is a producer-consumer pair commonly for replicating data between individual clusters, but can be used with the same source and destination settings. You just need to ensure you are not creating a feedback loop.  You would need to apply "custom logic" on that (and change the topic name), with what is [called a Handler class that is placed on your Kafka classpath](https://github.com/gwenshap/kafka-examples/tree/master/MirrorMakerHandler)

```
bin/kafka-mirror-maker.sh

...

--message.handler <String: A custom      Message handler which will process
  message handler of type                  every record in-between consumer and
  MirrorMakerMessageHandler>               producer.
--message.handler.args <String:          Arguments used by custom message
  Arguments passed to message handler      handler for mirror maker.
  constructor.>
```

[Confluent MirrorMaker documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc/mirrormaker.html)
[Kafka MirrorMaker documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330)

---

There is nothing stopping you from implementing the Connect API, and it may be easier to manage than a Kafka Streams application without an external cluster manager. Plus, since Connect is a Java library, you could in theory use Streams library internally within that.

Comment: @cricket-007 Thanks, we've been considering mirror maker too, I didn't know we can have a `message.hanlder` to deal with custom processing.

Comment: Welcome - Also https://github.com/gwenshap/kafka-examples/tree/master/MirrorMakerHandler